# Adding space between a list of text not working?

Tags: swiftui

The body of my view looks like this:

```
var body: some View {
         List {
            Section(header: Text("Verses")) {
                
                ForEach(self.viewModel.verses) { verse in
                    NavigationLink(destination: VerseDetailView(verse: verse), label: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                            Text(verse.verse).fontWeight(.medium)
                            Text("No \(verse.verse_number)").foregroundColor(.gray)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }).padding(10)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())

    }
```

Which produces:

[image]

I would like to add some space/margin between each cell to create a card-like structure, such as with [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/listrowinsets(_:)).

I tried all possible values in

```
                   .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0,
                                         leading: 25,
                                         bottom: 0,
                                         trailing: 0))
```

The cells don't move - no padding, no margin. Whats the issue?

Comment: The problem that you are encountering is that you what to use a carousel list style, but that is only implemented on watchOS. You can do a custom style by creating your own view and putting it into a generic `ScrollView`.

Comment: I don't follow. `listRowInsets` only works on WatchOS? What is my solution then? Wrap the entire thing in a `ScrollView`?

Comment: I am presuming your wanted it to look like [this](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/0b10922ed606478b5a4155f90ed18221/10700/SwiftUI-View-ListRowInsets@2x.png) which is a carousel list style. I think you think that `listRowInsets` is what creates the card like structure on the watch. `listRowInsets` is used to add what is inside the cell, not separate the different cell.

Comment: Okay - whats the procedure then

Comment: What iOS version?

Comment: iOS Version 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example that does the same thing. You can play around with things to get it the look to your liking. I simply stuck it in a `ZStack` with 1 column. That simply presents a detail view which you can customize as you want.

```
struct CarouselGridView: View {
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible())]
    let spacing: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue.opacity(0.15)
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: spacing) {
                    ForEach(loremIpsum, id: \.self) { item in
                        CarouselDetailView(someText: item)
                            .shadow(radius: 100)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CarouselDetailView: View {
    
    let someText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(someText)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I assumed it'd be way easier to add some spacing to each item in a list though

Comment: Yes and no. You would do that through padding. In this case, the LazyVGrid handles the spacing. Either way is relatively straightforward.